# What should the key value be in postman to map to a collection that holds a FormFile? How can i map to IFormfile using postman

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, postman

**What im trying to do** - Im building a endpoint with .net and the method holds a class called
TestRequest. And that class holds a collection of attachments. And a Attachment class holding a File and a FileId. Now i want to test my endpoint and send a post request with postman using form-data in body. *And my key in postman is Attachments[0].File and then im selecting a file.*

**The problem** - When im sending the request to the Create endpoint i getting a 400 Bad Request thown in my face because "The Attachments field is required.".. Yeah i know man, im trying :)

**What my goal is ** - My goal is to send a HTTP POST request to this Create endpoint with a body containing one or more Files and a FileId mapped to the TestRequest object.

```
public class Attachment
{
    public Guid FileId { get; set; }
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}

public class TestRequest
{
    public ICollection<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
}

[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]        
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([FromForm] TestRequest request) {
        return Ok("Test");
    }
}
```

[POSTMAN REQUEST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCbCk.png)}

What i can see using swagger is that the file is a string in some wierd way.
[SWAGGER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrSmy.png)

Comment: First of all, as your controller is `[Authorize]` so need to check the token, then check if the class property name has matched accordingly. I think you are passing the value in wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

> When im sending the request to the Create endpoint i getting a 400 Bad
> Request thown in my face because "The Attachments field is
> required.".. Yeah i know man, im trying :)

Based on your shared code snippet and scenario, I have tried to reproduced your issue and from my investigation, I ended up with the expected result. Also your code is correct.

You haven't shared which version of .NET you are using. However, I have tested your scenario with `.NET 8` and the controller code I kept same.

Upon my testing, I would say, first try to test without your `[Authorize]` so that we can narrow down the issue at least to ensure `[Authorize]` doesn't blocking us.

Once you have tried with that, then check your program.cs file if other middleware causing that issue. Why I am saying is that, I have another project where I have also tried your code which causing the issue becuase I have couple of other endpoint configuration which creating the route confilct and ended up with 401.

The project I have tested with and got the expected result has following progra.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Note:** Please double check your middleware order and make sure existing doesn't creating route conflict. Most importantly, be sure, your auth is correct and check if there is any CORS issue.

Comment: Thanks! it was a middleware that was the problem. Super thankfull for your answere.
Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the update, Glad to assist you on this.